# How do I add an additional Makefile step for a single target?

Tags: makefile

I have a `Makefile` that looks like this, going from `.o -> .bin -> .stub` for most targets. But I have another more complicated target that I want to generate through `.o -> .elf -> .bin -> .stub`.

```
all: simple.stub complex.stub

%.bin:  %.o
    $(Q)echo "  OBJCOPY $@"
    $(Q)$(OBJCOPY) -O binary $< $@

%.stub: %.bin
    $(Q)echo "  HEXDUMP $@"
    $(Q)$(HEXDUMP) -v -e '/2 "0x%04X, "' $< > $@

%.elf: %.o
    arm-none-eabi-gcc $< %@
```

How do I tell `make` that `.o -> .bin` is not a valid transition while building `complex.stub`, and also prevent it from going through `.elf` for the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `make` about the exception to the rule, and provide an alternative pattern rule as there are no built-in rules for `%.bin: %.elf`

```
.PHONY: all
all: simple.stub complex.stub

.INTERMEDIATE: complex.bin complex.elf

complex.bin: complex.elf

%.bin: %.o
    @echo Making $@ from $^
    @echo "test" > $@

%.bin: %.elf
    @echo Making $@ from $^
    @echo "test" > $@

%.stub: %.bin
    @echo Making $@ from $^
    @echo "test" > $@

%.elf: %.o
    @echo Making $@ from $^
    @echo "test" > $@

%.o:
    @echo Making $@
    @echo "test" > $@
```

`.INTERMEDIATE` isn't strictly necessary, it's just a useful auto cleanup seeing as it's unlikely you need to keep the intermediate files around.